# RF amplifier biasing in QUCs

Tags: amplifier, rf, qucs

I have selected an infineon BFP840ESD BJT to work with in the design of a low noise RF amplifier. I'm trying to use Qucs Studio to simulate it.

From the datasheet I select my bias conditions with as low a possible value of Ic to give better noise performance. I select \$I_c=6mA\$ and \$V_{CE}=1.8V\$ with a corresponding base current of \$20\mu A\$:

[image: Bias conditions]

I'd like to use this simple biasing setup using RF chokes and DC blocks:

[image: Biasing Configuration]

I calculate \$R_b = \frac{V_{bb}-0.7}{I_b} = \frac{1.8-0.7}{20\mu A} = 55 000 \Omega\$

I set up the simulation as follows in QUCS studio:

[image: QUCS setup]

I've selected the file to use in the s-parameter block as a .s2p provided by the manufacturer generated for the same bias conditions as above.

I'm expecting to read 6mA on the ammeter when I run the calculate DC bias function to verify the biasing however I am reading 0 as shown above. I'm completely new to using both QUCs and designing RF amplifiers so I am at a bit of a loss for what I'm doing wrong.

Could anyone help me understand how to correctly bias an RF transistor and set it up for simulation using s-parameters in QUCS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an S-parameter model. An S-parameter model is a **small signal** model of a device and is only valid within a certain frequency range. Also this S-parameter model might be valid only for a certain biasing condition (this is indeed the case here).

That frequency range generally does **not** include DC (0 Hz) so you cannot and should not expect that an S-parameter model will properly model the DC behavior of the device.

To check the biasing, don't use the S-parameter model, instead use a proper transistor model.

I would simply remove the S-parameter model in the schematic and replace it with a "normal" transistor model. Then check the biasing. If the biasing is incorrect, make changes until it is correct.

Then **copy** that schematic and in that copy, replace the transistor model by the S-parameter model. In this copy, since it uses an S-parameter model, it is only useful to do **small signal** analysis, so AC and/or S-parameter.

If you'd do a transient (time) simulation with the S-parameter model and apply 1000 V at the input, the amplifier would work just fine as the S-parameter model is a **linearized model** and it doesn't care about voltage values. You can see an S-parameter model as a combination of resistors, capacitors, inductors and (sometimes) coupling between inductors. There are is diodes like behavior in an S-parameter model.

Comment: so I should rather use the spice model to verify that the bias conditions are working and once I've done so I can put the s parameters back?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my point.